# excel, Apache Poi, unable to write to cell

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have been given a project which requires me to extract information from an excel file, 
do some calculations on the data and write the information back to an excel sheet. for some 
reason a part of my data just does feed into the cells.
 AN example is given below.

```
package ExcelDocs;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

public class Trial{

    public static void main(String[] agrs){

        Workbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet ws=wb.createSheet("Testing");
        Cell c1=ws.createRow(0).createCell(0);
        c1.setCellValue("hello");
        Cell c2=ws.createRow(1).createCell(1);
        c2.setCellValue("how are you?");
        for(int i=1;i<7;i++){
            Cell c3=ws.createRow(i).createCell(0);
            c3.setCellValue(i);
        }

        try{ 
            FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream("ANISH.xlsx");
            wb.write(out);
            out.close();
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("unable to write to excel");
        }

    }
}
```

This code should generate the following output:

```
      COL1     COL2
ROW1  hello
ROW2           how are you?
ROW3
ROW4
ROW5
ROW6
ROW7
```

instead I get this as the output

```
      COL1     COL2
ROW1  hello
ROW2           
ROW3
ROW4
ROW5
ROW6
ROW7
```

can anyone tell me why the "how are you?" is getting deleted?
I facing the same problem in my other programs too.

Comment: ohh sorry 
1
2
3
4
5
6 is also being written. only the "how are you?" gets deleted

Answer (score 2):

This line is getting overwritten with the line in the for loop:

```
Cell c2=ws.createRow(1).createCell(1);
```

Comment: but im trying to write "1" in the cell to the left of it.
so why does the "how are you get deleted?"
and how can i overcome this problem?

Comment: But it re-creates the whole row including the column where you wrote `how are you?`

Comment: change the loop counter to start from 2: `for(int i=2; i<7; i++) {`

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're overwriting the row created at index 1 in this `for` loop.

```
for(int i=1;i<7;i++){ // when i = 1
    Cell c3=ws.createRow(i).createCell(0); // it recreates a row at that index
    c3.setCellValue(i); // and re-writes it here in the loop.
}
```

You need to change the loop to start creating rows from the index 2.

```
for(int i=2; i<7; i++) { // now it starts from row index 2 and doesn't overwrite your previous row created at index 1
    Cell c3=ws.createRow(i).createCell(0); 
    c3.setCellValue(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `for` loop the `createRow` is trashing the row that you created before.

So, before the loop, when you do `Cell c2=ws.createRow(1).createCell(1);`  change this so that the `Row` object is saved.

```
Row r = Cell c2=ws.createRow(1);
r.createCell(1);
```

and use `r` in your loop too.